# how to redirect GCDWebServer requests to an external host from within an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, gcdwebserver

In my iOS app I'm trying to add a simple [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) redirect handler like so:

```
self.webServer!.addHandlerForMethod("GET", 
    pathRegex: "/api/.*",
    requestClass: GCDWebServerRequest.self,
    processBlock: { request in
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://external.host\(request.URL!.absoluteString)")
        return GCDWebServerResponse(redirect: url, permanent: true)
    }
)
```

but my `url` is malformed. How do I properly construct an `NSURL` from a given `host` and `GCDWebServerRequest.URL` ?

Comment: What is the value of `url`? It seems like your current construction might end up with two schemes, which would be invalid.

Comment: Ah, it is `nil` ! It appears my `url` is indeed malformed. If I hardcode an external url such as `let url = NSURL(string: "http://external.host/api/playthrough_ids")` then it works. So I'll edit the question, to rephrase 'how to form a proper `NSURL` with host + `request.URL`

Answer (score 0):

`request.URL` is an `NSURL` object and as such, using it to form another url with a different host necessitates splitting it by accessing its `path` like so:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://host.com\(request.URL!.path)")
```